# Event and Observable in FSharp

Tags: events, f#, observable, reactive-programming

Is it equivalent/better to work

- with the [Event module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340422.aspx) on [Event type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370608.aspx)
- or with Observable on the [publish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353807.aspx) property of an event

Functionally it seems equivalent, and I guess the difference is 'semantic' :

- Are we inside the boundary where it makes sense to have access to the internal state of 
  the event ?
- Or are we considering this [event interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340439.aspx) as a passive source from which a stream was exposed to us

Is that the correct thinking ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The main difference between `Event` and `Observable` is in how they handle state and un-subscription.

- **Event** functions attach to the source event and do not give you any way to unsubscribe. If you use stateful combinators (like [`Event.scan`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-eventmodule.html#scan)) and then attach multiple observers to the resulting event, then they will all see the same state.
- **Observable** functions construct "specification" of the processing pipeline. When you attach a handler to `IObservable` value, you get back an `IDisposable` that can be used to remove all handlers. Each handler attached to `IObservable` will get a new state (because the runtime creates a new processing chain according to the "specification").

In practice, the main difference is in the statfullness - if you want to share state, you can use the `Event` module - implementing the same using `Observable` is possible but harder.

If you're using events inside `async`, then you should use `Observable` and `AwaitObservable` (instead of built-in `AwaitEvent`), because using event combinators will leak memory - it will attach event handlers that are never removed.

Comment: The difference is far from being obvious at first, and the word (E)event quite overloaded.

Comment: @Nicolas That's true. It follows from historical reasons (F# had `Event` module before `IObservable` existed - and maybe the right thing was to remove it). But to be honest, things would be easier if .NET did not have special "events" in the first place, but that has been decided too long ago :-).