# F#: unsubscribe from an FSharp.Control.Reactive.Observable

Tags: f#, system.reactive, observable

I have been unable to find a definitive answer to how one would go about unsubscribing from an `Observable`, which was subscribed to with `Observable.subscribe(...)`. There is another SO answer here ([Event and Observable in FSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549384/event-and-observable-in-fsharp/15549844#15549844)), which comes tantalisingly close, but does not explicitly state as to how this is achieved, unless I'm missing something.

The call to `Observable.subscribe( someSubscriptionFunction )` returns an `IDisposable`. Do I simply need to `.Dispose()` it to remove `someSubscriptionFunction` (and only it), or does this have effect on the `Observable` as well, or any of the other subscriptions to this `Observable`?

Comment: Why do you need to .Dispose? But if you do, then it will dispose of the subscription. You could also use gjallarhorn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you only need to unsubscribe if you want to stop receiving notifications before the observer would normally stop sending them (e.g. before triggering `OnCompleted` or `OnError`).

In order to get a handle on how observables behave, it's probably clearest to look behind the F# interface to the underlying library.

The intention of the `IDisposable` returned by `Observable.subscribe` is that it unsubscribes a single `IObserver` from the `IObservable`.

> The provider must implement a single method, Subscribe, that indicates
>   that an observer wants to receive push-based notifications. Callers to
>   the method pass an instance of the observer. The method returns an
>   IDisposable implementation that enables observers to cancel
>   notifications at any time before the provider has stopped sending
>   them.

([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782981(v=vs.110).aspx))

You can see this behaviour from the [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) implementation provided here (in C#, sadly the page is lacking F# samples):

The relevant snippet is:

```
private class Unsubscriber : IDisposable
{
    private List<IObserver<Location>>_observers;
    private IObserver<Location> _observer;

    public Unsubscriber(List<IObserver<Location>> observers, IObserver<Location> observer)
    {
        this._observers = observers;
        this._observer = observer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_observer != null && _observers.Contains(_observer))
            _observers.Remove(_observer);
    }
}
```

Of course, because these are interfaces, you're totally at the mercy of the implementer in terms of actual behaviour.

---

So, in terms of actually removing the subscription, yes, all you need to do is to `Dispose()` the `IDisposable` and no, it should not have an impact on any other observers.

You could also use the `use` or `using` keywords rather than explicitly called dispose.  See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/resource-management-the-use-keyword-%5Bfsharp%5D) for more.